# Mutate Nokogiri XML Document Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am trying to edit a big XML file with Nokogiri. Currently, I am able to find the NodeSet I am looking for using `.css` I can create the new NodeSet I would like to set as the replacement, but through using `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet#push` I am unable to change the xml document object's contents.

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('/Users/Desktop/metadata.xml')
keywords = xml.css('version').first.css('keywords keyword') ## node set I want to edit
keywords.delete(keywords[0]) ## one less element in the node set
xml.css('version').first.css('keywords keyword').remove ## destructively modifies xml object and erases all elements

## this is where things get interesting: 
## this call returns a new node set with keywords[0] inside of it, 
## but does NOT mutate the xml object
xml.css('version').first.css('keywords keyword').push(keywords[0])
puts xml.css('version').first.css('keywords keyword') ## puts an empty array
```

EDIT: Sample XML

```
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords>
      <keyword>this</keyword>
      <keyword>that</keyword>
      <keyword>the other</keyword>
    </keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
```

EDIT: Goal XML

```
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords>
      <keyword>that</keyword>
      <keyword>the other</keyword>
    </keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
```

***OR***

```
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords>
      <keyword>different keyword</keyword>
    </keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
```

Comment: You're missing a minimal sample of the XML to test against. Don't ask us to write our own just to help you.

Comment: Thank you for adding the XML, but it isn't valid for your question. It's missing a `<version>` tag entirely.

Comment: there you go. again: i appreciate the help.

Comment: Now show what the resulting XML should look like please.

Comment: just added in what i am looking for. in this particular example, i am trying to just delete one of the elements in the nodeset. however there is going to come a time when i am going to need to add in elements. the point is really that when i have the replacement nodeset, `.push` does not mutate the xml object it is called on.

Comment: Then SHOW WHAT YOU WANT with additional sample output. Don't make us guess.

Comment: just added in an alternative output. you need to relax though.

Comment: I'm completely relaxed. It's important to understand that an incomplete question wastes our time. You're asking volunteers to take time to help you, and when you don't supply the necessary information up front it takes us even longer. I could have voted to close your question immediately, or downvoted you but you are new and need to know you have responsibilities when asking a question. The XML wasn't supplied, then wasn't correct, and it appears you changed your needs, or didn't do a good job explaining them. The appropriate response is different than "you need to relax".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32441/discussion-between-ohwutup-and-the-tin-man)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an XML sample I'm holding off trying to diagnose the problem, however your code isn't written well. These appear to be valid substitutions/changes:

- `keywords = xml.css('version').first` could be simplified to:

  ```
  xml.at('version')
  ```
- `xml.css('version').first.css('keywords keyword')` might be shortened to:

  ```
  xml.css('version 'keywords keyword')
  ```

but without the XML I can't confirm that.

Nokogiri's `at('some_selector')` is equivalent to `search('some_selector').first`. Similarly `at_css` and `at_xpath` are the equivalents of `css` and `xpath` searches followed by `first`.

---

Here's how I'd write it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords>
      <keyword>this</keyword>
      <keyword>that</keyword>
      <keyword>the other</keyword>
    </keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
</xml>
EOT

keywords = xml.css('version keywords keyword')
xml.at('version keywords').children = keywords[1..-1]
puts xml.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords><keyword>that</keyword><keyword>the other</keyword></keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
</xml>
```

In order for the XML to be correct `<version>` needs a wrapping "root" tag, which is why I added `<xml>`. I'm sure your original XML has something similar.

You can control how many and which existing `<keyword>` nodes are allowed to remain by slicing the `keywords` NodeSet.

---

> this doesnt tackle the issue in a generic enough way that i can add and modify existing children.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords>
      <keyword>this</keyword>
      <keyword>that</keyword>
      <keyword>the other</keyword>
    </keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
</xml>
EOT

version_keywords = xml.at('version keywords')
keywords = version_keywords.css('keyword')
version_keywords.children = keywords[1..-1]
version_keywords.add_child('<keyword>And now for something entirely different</keyword>')
puts xml.to_xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<version>
  <locale name="en-US">
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    <description>this is the description</description>
    <keywords><keyword>that</keyword><keyword>the other</keyword><keyword>And now for something entirely different</keyword></keywords>
  </locale>
</version>
</xml>
```

You can add a node simply by identifying where it goes, then using one of the many methods to insert a new one. You could even manipulate `keywords` and pass the entire NodeSet. You can use a string, or create a new Node instance. Nokogiri is happy with either one.

Those are some of the tools needed to find and change a node or its children. You'll need to take some time and read through [Nokogiri's XML::Node documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) to see what else is available and what fits your needs. You can get a lot more complex, but usually it's a very simple process to replace a node or move it around.

Comment: appreciate the help. i added in some sample xml.

Comment: thanks, but this doesnt tackle the issue in a generic enough way that i can add and modify existing children.

Comment: thanks. got it. also, i read the documentation. thats why i came to stack overflow, because their (poor) documentation didnt answer my question.

Comment: Nokogiri's documentation isn't poor, it's describing a complex subject that takes a while to understand. In my fairly extensive experience parsing/manipulating XML in many languages it's the best I've used.